# Interop Powerpoint,

Tags: interop, c#-3.0, powerpoint

I want to insert a picture in powerpoint and I am facing this error :

> (1. Solution exception:CustomLayouts (unknown member) : Integer out of
>   range. 36 is not in the valid range of 1 to 11.)

The problem is located this part of the code:

```
PowerPoint.CustomLayout Cus01 = pr01.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutPictureWithCaption];
```

The `pplayoutPictureWithCaption` has a number 36.
Any Ideas ??

```
if (trigger[0] == true)
{
    //Create a project
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
    app.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;

    //Create a presentation in thie project
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations pre = app.Presentations;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation pr01 = pre.Add(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation pr02 = app.ActivePresentation;

    //Create a slide in the project
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slides sl = pr02.Slides;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.CustomLayout Cus01 = pr01.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutPictureWithCaption];
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide sl01 = pr02.Slides.AddSlide(1, Cus01);


    //Insert Picture
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape shape = sl01.Shapes[2];
    sl01.Shapes.AddPicture("D:\\AliceProject\\sd.jpg", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 1, 1, 3, 3);
}
```

Comment: Please look: ppSlidelayout is a enumeration, so "PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutPictureWithCaption" is not valid

Comment: Thanks Christine. I am trying imitate this code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb870303(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: PowerPoint.Slide slide =
        presentation.Slides.Add(
        presentation.Slides.Count + 1,
        PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutPictureWithCaption);

Comment: I would assume that this example has an error or is version dependend, because the "ppSlideLayout" has no members "ppLayoutPictureWithCaption" (see [2007](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb251063(v=office.12).aspx) or [2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff746831.aspx)).  But it has in [2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.ppslidelayout(v=office.14).aspx). This Example will only work with Powerpoint 2010

Comment: All the examples I have seen they are using the same overload. I am also using powerpoint 2010. do you have an idea on how to solve it ?

Comment: The thing is that from 1 to 11 is the range. So even ini the link you have sent to me there are some members that cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when using [NetOffice](https://github.com/NetOfficeFw/NetOffice) + powerpoint 2013. But if I directly set the type when creating the slide it works

```
presentation.Slides.Add(presentation.Slides.Count + 1, PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutPictureWithCaption);
```